# Environmental Variable for PROMPT?

Tags: windows, unix, system, environment

I want to make my command prompt a little more like Unix. I made a PROMPT system variable that's set to PC-name > 
But I want that to include the current folder I'm in, not the entire path. Like if I set PROMPT to pwd it gives the whole path but i just want the directory i'm currently in on the prompt so i know which folder i'm in. Any ideas how  to achieve this?

For example the prompt would be PC-name stuff > 
if im in the stuff folder
C:\Users\Name\folder\stuff

Set a variable to this? and update environment var somehow?:

```
for %%* in (.) do @echo %%~n*
```

Comment: I see no way to get just the last directory name in the path to show as the prompt..

Comment: there's no way to change it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, this just isn't possible with the default windows **cmd** command shell (and this question probably belongs on [Super User](https://superuser.com/)).

You can type 'prompt /?' to see your options, and you can place environment variables in the prompt via %envvar%, but there is no "leaf" env var set for you.  I'm not aware of any way to set one via the standard 'cd' command (although if you're willing to use a non-standard change-directory command, you could probably wire something up.)

You could use an alternate shell:

- the [Cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/) shell is popular with *nix users using Windows, as it provides traditional bash (or alternate) shell support and commands.
- the built-in Powershell, which has a more programmable prompt (but is not very *nix-ish)

e.g.

```
function prompt { 
    $p = Split-Path -leaf -path (Get-Location);
    $c = $env:computername;
    "$c $p> " 
}
```

Which can be set in your powershell profile:

```
%userprofile%\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1
```

Comment: this is close, but it gives the entire path.

Comment: can a variable be set to the result of a batch file?